# Error in Vs code Insider 'undefined symbol for architecture arm64'

Tags: arrays, c, visual-studio-code

I am just running a basic program on my Mac m1 in CPP. this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main({
int i, n, num, pos, arr[10];
printf("\n Enter the number of elements in the array");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("\n arr[%d] = ", I);
scanf("%d", &arr[i]);}
printf("\n Enter the number to be inserted : ");
scanf("%d", &num);
printf("\n Enter the position at which the number has to be added : ");
scanf("%d", &pos);
for(i=n-1;i>=pos;i--)
arr[i+1] = arr[i];
arr[pos] = num;
n = n+1;
printf("\n The array after insertion of %d is : ",num);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
printf("\n arr[%d] =%d", i, arr[i]);}
```

Everytime I run this code I get this error:

```
[Running] cd "/Users/siddhpurohit/Documents/vs code/DSU/" && gcc Exp1.c -o Exp1 && "/Users/siddhpurohit/Documents/vs code/DSU/"Exp1
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:


"_main", referenced from:
 implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.227 seconds
```

If you know how to correct this error please let me know. I am a newbie and don't know much about coding... but I am hoping to learn.

Comment: `int main({`?? Is that really what your code looks like? It should be `int main(int argc, char **argv) { ...}` or `int main(void) { .. }`

Comment: AFAIK there is no official support in gcc for M1 arm builds yet. There is work in progress here: https://github.com/iains/gcc-darwin-arm64. You may be able to run the x86 binary with Rosetta but I'm not an expert on that so can't provide any further info along those lines.

Comment: Please indent your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int i,n,num,pos,arr[10];
printf("\n enter the number of elements in the array");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("\n arr[%d] = ",i);
printf("\n enter the number to be inserted: ");
scanf("%d",&num);
printf("\n enter the position at which the number has to be added :");
scanf("%d",&pos);
for(i=n-1;i>=pos;i--)
arr[i+1]=arr[i];
arr[pos]=num;
n=n+1;
printf("\n the array after insertion of %d is : ",num);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
printf("\n arr[%d] =%d",i,arr[i]);}
```

Comment: now this one work properly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).